# How to use async function to await user input from onClick?

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await

I am trying to fetch  data from an external  api and I use `async` and `await`. I want to wait for user input  from an `onClick` function and  then to pass the url to an async function and to get the data in json format form that url.
OnClick function is working:

```
onClick(){
   this.data=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('data')).value;
    
   return this.url='https://api.url.info/feed/'+this.data
}
```

When I use `console.log(data2)` undefined an the next error: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

```
async getData(){
    var data2=this.url;
    const response=await fetch(this.url);
    this.data=await response.json();
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.getData();
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="data"  value=""/>
<button type="button" (click)="onClick()" id="btn">Search</button>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular but the general approach is to call the fetching function inside the event handler. That event handler is already the way to wait for user input. About `async/await` specifically: A promise can only resolve once, so it can't represent an event handler that can fire multiple times.

Comment: Hi Santal, I'd definitely recommend you to read the angular documentation https://angular.io/docs as accessing DOM elements by using `document` is not the way to go. Angular is here especially for that, to simplify your life and abstract this away. Same for the HTTP layer. Angular `HttpClient` which lets you do HTTP requests instead of doing `fetch` yourself.

Comment: @maxime1992 is correct. If you share with us your HTML template, we can give you an example with the correct Angular way of doing both tasks.

Comment: I edit my post and now i have the html template

Comment: I still don't see the HTML element with the id equal to "data" which is what you are trying to access.

Comment: Sorry i change the id when i made this post to be more clear,i updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I made a working solution following the Angular best practices, the code is commented to help you understand it better.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tqhd32)

**Template**

```
<input #yourData id="data" type="text" id="input"  value=""/>
<button type="button" (click)="onClick()" id="btn">Search</button>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({ ... })
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any; // The api response is going to be stored here
  baseUrl: string = 'https://api.url.info/feed/';

  // You need to import the HttpClientModule on your module (in the AppModule is fine)
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // One of the proper ways to access
  // Documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild
  @ViewChild("yourData", { static: true }) yourTemplateElement: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

  // Use ngOnInit if the static option is set to true, use ngAfterViewInit otherwise
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.data = await this.getData(this.baseUrl);
  }

  getData(url: string): any {
    // Use the http client service to make http calls.
    // By default it returns an observable but since you want to use
    // the async/await keywords, we need to convert it into a promise
    return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
  }

  async onClick() {
    const urlSegment = this.yourTemplateElement.nativeElement.value;
    this.data = await this.getData(this.baseUrl + urlSegment);
  }
}
```

Comment: I used this demo and is working,i have one more question (if you want to help me):i got the api response in a json format and i want to use  reduce function to get  a specific value from the response and i get this error :TypeError: this.reduce is not a function .

Comment: I will do my best to help but more information might be required. The `this` keyword in this case will refer to the class instance (in your case, your component) and since you don't have such a method, that error is thrown. I'm deducing that you are trying to use the arrays reduce method, correct? So it should be something like `this.data.reduce(...)` but since you want to get a specific value from the list, maybe the array `find` method would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In your onClick method, call the getData() method and don't call `this.getData()` in `ngOnInit`. Your code should look like:

```
onClick(){
    this.data=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('data')).value;
    const url='https://api.url.info/feed/'+this.data;
    this.getData(url);
  }
```

```
async getData(url){
    const response=await fetch(url);
     this.data=await response.json();
  }
```

Comment: Your example is a bit confusing because you are passing the URL to `getData` as well as assigning it to `this.url` and you are accessing both the parameter and `this.url` in `getData`. I'd recommend to clean this up a bit to make it less confusing.

Comment: You were right to point out. I have update the answer.

Comment: While this may work I'd strongly advise you against doing things like that when working with Angular. You are going in the opposite direction of good practices. Refer to my initial comment